# Approach for authentication and storing user details

Tags: php, mysql, session, caching

I am using the Zend Framework but my question is broadly about sessions / databases / auth (PHP MySQL).

Currently this is my approach to authentication:

1) User signs in, the details are checked in database.
- Standard stuff really.

2) If the details are correct only the user's unique ID is stored in the session and a security token (user unique ID + IP + Browser info + salt). The session in written to the filesystem.

- I've been reading around and many are saying that storing stuff in sessions is not a good idea, and that you should really only write a unique ID which refers back to the user's details and a security token to prevent session hijacking. So this is the approach i've taken, i use to write the user's details in session, but i've moved that out. Wanted to know your opinions on this.
- I'm keeping sessions in the filesystem since i don't run on multiple servers, and since i'm only writting a tiny tiny bit of data to sessions, i thought that performance would be greater keeping sessions in the filesystem to reduce load on the database. Once the session is written on authentication, it really is only read-only from then on.

3) The rest of the user's details (like subscription details, permissions, account info etc) are cached in the filesystem (this can always be easily moved to memory if i wanted even more performance).

- So rather than keeping the user's details in session, the user's details are cached in the file system. I'm using Zend_Cache and the unique cache id is something like md5(/cache/auth/2892), the number is the unique id of the user. I guess the benefit of this method is that once the user is logged in, there is essentially not database queries being run to get the user's details. Just wonder if this approach is better than keeping the whole lot in session...

4) As the user moves throughout the site the only thing that is checked is the ID in the session and the security token.

So, overall the first question is 1) is the filesystem more efficient than a database for this purpose 2) have i taken enough security precautions 3) is separating user detail's from the session into a cached file a pointless task?

Thanks.

Comment: How big load are we talking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're asking a range of things.

**Sessions**

Sessions in PHP are fast and efficient. Thousands of small disk-based sessions on a moderately up-to-date server is not going to be a performance bottleneck. Neither is writing your own handlers (very easy; the PHP manual has examples) to put it in a database.

About the only best-practice rules about sessions is: only give the web browser one thing, the session ID. Putting just the logged in userid in the session and retrieving those details from the DB when you need them is also best-practice. It also means that user information can be changed and they get it on the next page update.

It doesn't sound like you will have this problem but beware of just throwing a lot of stuff into a session. A few K of data (say, a few dozen scalars) is fine. Tossing many objects and large arrays of data in there will be noticed. If you do this for a specific page, remember to throw it away in the session once the page is done with it.

You may also want to implement your own login timeout with a session variable. The garbage collection settings in `php.ini` are intended for managing the storage of session data, not for doing login timeouts.

**Caching**

This is a complex topic and you will probably need to start gathering metrics (generally page load times) before implementing anything.

To implement any sort of caching, you do need to consider the lifetime of the data you're caching and how expensive re-generating it will be on a cache miss. Just throwing memcache at the problem is *not* a solution; you still need to understand your caching parameters and how memcache interprets them. This also applies to any persistent storage solution, including disk-based sessions, but I'm highlighting memcache because it is high-profile and has quite an aggressive expiry mechanism.

An often overlooked example is loading the same data from the database multiple times in a page: a good ORM will do that for you without relying on MySQL query caching. Another overlooked example are small queries that run on every page: caching these for just a few seconds on a moderately busy server and the database load will drop considerably.

Finally, caching at multiple levels is often much more effective and scalable than once because they can leverage each other's expiries. It also abstracts well: for example, hide it in your ORM and it's theoretically available invisibly and automatically for *all* your objects.

Answer (score 0):

1) You can easily test which is faster by making a loop script. Anyway, a drawback with using the filesystem is that you need to update the cached file everytime you update the db. Copies of data is in general a bad thing. Also, unless you have millions of visitors I dont think there will be any practical diffrence regarding speed in any of the stratagies. And... not to forget, sessions are also stored in the filesystem. One file for each session.

Is a query faster then the filesystem: Depends. Is query caching enabled. In MySql it is by default, and than you might be lucky and only need a memory access. If not, the db needs to do a filesystem accass anyway. Second, how optimized is your query with index's. How buissy is the server harddisk.

3) Depends on the speed of fetching it from db. In general, caching can do magic to speed performance, but caching in memory would be even better by using memcached or something similar. In general i would avoid copies of the data in files. But of course, if it takes secods to query the data from the db, than go for filesystem caching. Also, if you have many users.. like 10.000+ you have to make some folder system, since putting 10.000 cached files in the same folder slows downs the accesstime...